# multiple selection using mouse drag

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) v3.0.0-rc.22 in my application.

I use selection features of it and everything work fine, but i want to use selection using mouse drag.

Is it possible to select multiple row using mouse drag.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You can select multiple rows by holding CTRL+Shift and then left-clicking on the first and last rows of the interval of rows you want to select.